# Does Oracle Instant Client Basic Lite 11.2.0.3.0 for Win32 exist?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, instantclient

ODP.NET [11.2.0.3.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html) was released on December 28, 2011 and its description says that it contains Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.3.0. Since I'm distributing the Instant Client binaries directly with my application I'm using the Basic Lite version of the instant client to reduce file sizes. So I tried to download the new Basic Lite version like I previously did when ODP.NET was updated, but there is no Win32 download of Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.3.0. The [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) shows 11.2.0.2.0 as the latest version.

Is the new Basic Lite version available anywhere? Or can I just use the old one?

**edit:** Found an answer to the second question myself in the release notes:

> ODP.NET requires Oracle Client 11.2.0.3.0 or Oracle Instant Client
>   11.2.0.3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Oracle forum I've now found the lite DLL in the non-xcopy download (ODTwithODAC112030.zip).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you ran into a specific bug on 11.2.0.2.0 that you know is fixed in 11.2.0.3.0, you should be fine with 11.2.0.2.0.

-Mark

Comment: Do you mean the Instant Client or ODP.NET in general? Because my last question was if I can use the new ODP.NET with the old Instant Client Basic Lite.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update an old question, 11.2.0.3.0 for Windows 32-bit is now (as of July 2013) available on the downloads page that the question references: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html